# Where in the JLS is the explanation for it to be legal the assignment of a raw type to an unbounded type?

Tags: java, generics, jls

I'm looking for a JLS quote for the following sentence to be legal:

```
Vector<?> vector = PreJava5API.getRawVector();
```

Comment: Do you mean why does it not result in a compile-time error (which it does not, not even if you replace the wildcard with `String`), or why there is not even a warning (why would you want one here, the wildcard quite limits unsafe operations you can do from here one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start from the section about  assignment

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1

which allows assignment conversion

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2

which allows unchecked conversion

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9

which allows conversion from raw `G` to `G<?>`, without a warning.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a quote for you ([4.8. Raw Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)):

> The warnings from unchecked conversion cover the dual case, where a generified consumer uses a legacy library. For example, a method of the library has the raw return type Vector, but the consumer assigns the result of the method invocation to a variable of type Vector<String>. This is unsafe, since the raw vector might have had a different element type than String, but is still permitted using unchecked conversion in order to enable interfacing with legacy code. The warning from unchecked conversion indicates that the generified consumer may experience problems from heap pollution at other points in the program.

So you get a warning (not an error!) for

```
Vector<String> vector = PreJava5API.getRawVector();
```

This is to facilitate interoperability with legacy code.

A safer version is to use wildcards (as in your example). With those, you are severely limited in how you can use the `vector`, thus making it safe, and there is no need for even a warning anymore: All you can do is pull out `Object` (which always works). You cannot add anything to `vector` (so that part is safe, too).

Comment: Your quote covers why it compiles with a warning using a type like `Vector<String>`, is there in the JLS something about the `Vector<?>` compiling without producing any warning?, I understand why it is safe to use a type declaration like that, I'm just trying to get all the words from the JLS.

Comment: How about section 5.1.9 (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.9): "Use of an unchecked conversion causes a compile-time unchecked warning unless [the type converted to] is a parameterized type in which all type arguments are unbounded wildcards"

Comment: That quote made it clear, could you please update your answer to accept it?